# Invalid configured shell error when running the official FreeBSD vagrant box

Tags: ssh, vagrant, freebsd, vagrantfile

I tried to run the official FreeBSD vagrant box by using:

```
vagrant init freebsd/FreeBSD-10.2-STABLE
```

And afterwards, modified my Vagrantfile accordingly based on the instructions at https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/52717/ by adding the following lines:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.guest = :freebsd
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", id: "vagrant-root", disabled: true
  config.vm.box = "freebsd/FreeBSD-10.2-STABLE"
  config.ssh.shell = "sh"
  config.vm.base_mac = "080027D14C66"

  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "1024"]
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--cpus", "1"]
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--hwvirtex", "on"]
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--audio", "none"]
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--nictype1", "virtio"]
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--nictype2", "virtio"]
  end
end
```

When I issue the vagrant up command:

```
vagrant up --provider virtualbox
```

the following error was shown:

> The configured shell (config.ssh.shell) is invalid and unable to
>   properly execute commands. The most common cause for this is using a
>   shell that is unavailable on the system. Please verify you're using
>   the full path to the shell and that the shell is executable by the SSH
>   user.

Regardless of the error, I'm still able to `vagrant ssh` into the box. However, I'm not able to gracefully shutdown the machine using `vagrant halt`. It would show the same error as above and does not shutdown at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fix was simple as it was a totally noob mistake on my part. In the Vagrantfile, you should remove all the parts generated when running `vagrant init` command except for the two lines at the very top. Then paste the suggested ones below those two lines. The complete Vagrantfile should be like the following:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.vm.guest = :freebsd
    config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", id: "vagrant-root", disabled: true
    config.vm.box = "freebsd/FreeBSD-10.2-STABLE"
    config.ssh.shell = "sh"
    config.vm.base_mac = "080027D14C66"

    config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
      vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "1024"]
      vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--cpus", "1"]
      vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--hwvirtex", "on"]
      vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--audio", "none"]
      vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--nictype1", "virtio"]
      vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--nictype2", "virtio"]
    end

    config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
end
```

What I did wrong was nesting this `Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|` block inside the auto-generated one.